# Register only a single tap in touchesBegan regardless how long finger is held on screen?

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit

I'm working on a platform game and used to have a single press give a static heigh jump. My jumping code was all in touches began:

```
    let zero:CGFloat = 0

    //added the if velocity greater == zero for the most part wont allow players to jump onless on ground
    if((Player.isPlayerOnGround) && (player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy)! == zero) || Player.isPlayerOnPlatform {

        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: jumpHeight))

        Player.isPlayerOnGround = false
    }
```

I found a platformer tutorial from Ray Wenderlich with a snippet of code to allow the player to do a short hop, or a full hope depending on if you tapped the screen lightly or held it. Ray puts this code in the UPDATE method though:

```
CGPoint jumpForce = ccp(0.0, 310.0);
  float jumpCutoff = 150.0;

  if (self.mightAsWellJump && self.onGround) {
    self.velocity = ccpAdd(self.velocity, jumpForce);
  } else if (!self.mightAsWellJump && self.velocity.y > jumpCutoff) {
    self.velocity = ccp(self.velocity.x, jumpCutoff);
  }
```

I applied his method to my own project in my update method and it works. The only problem is, if the screen is held down the player continues to jump.

I have a Bool check to not allow the player to jump if he's not on the ground, however if the screen tap is held then the player jumps and repeatedly touches the ground and continues to jump forever.

Given this, I can't figure out the logic of turning off touch recognition in touches began once my character is in the air and not have it turn back on until I lift my finger and tap again.

any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a Boolean called isJumping that is set to true when TouchesBegan and is back to False when TouchesEnded. Check inside the jump method if this boolean is true (meaning that the finger is still on), if so don't jump! Make sure to set this boolean as the last line in touches began just to not exit the first jump!

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and i can't seem to get it to work. I think because as long as i keep my finger on the screen isJumping is always equal to true right?

Comment: Sorry my answer was quick because I was in work so I had limited time. Glad it worked :D!